# HammerJS v2.0.4 - Gesture callback function with Custom Parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, gesture, hammer.js

I am using HammerJS v2.0.4 (independent - no Hammer jQuery Plugin). I wanted to have a callback function with my own parameters. I am not sure how to pass custom parameters to gesture callback function. Here what I am trying to do (without custom parameters):

```
// get hammer fuction 
function getGesture(element){
    // instantiate hammer - $(this).get[0] gives me a <div>  
    var gesture =  new Hammer.Manager($(this).get[0]);

    // add hammer gestures
    gesture.add(new Hammer.Pan({ threshold: 0, pointers: 0 }));
    gesture.add(new Hammer.Swipe()).recognizeWith(gesture.get('pan'));

    // gesture and callback without custom parametr
    gesture.on('panstart panmove', this.panRecognizer); 

    // But I wanted something like 
    // gesture.on('panstart panmove', this.panRecognizer, this) 
    // where 'this' is a custom parameter

    gesture.on('swipe', this.swipeRecognizer); // same as above
}

function panRecognizer(ev, self){
    // do something with self and ev
}

function swipeRecognizer(ev, self){
    // do something with self and ev
}
```

can anyone help me with this please? I am new to JS

Comment: anybody there to help?